# Unable to convert dataframe column list into a traditional data frame vector

Tags: r, list, dataframe, dplyr

Having an issue with a dataframe where one of the columns is a list of dates.
Looking to convert the list to a vector column in the data frame.

when I use `head(output)` the dates show correctly.  When I view the dataframe they show correctly.  when I use `output$date`, I get:

(EXAMPLE)

```
[[239]]
character(0)

[[240]]
character(0)

[[241]]
character(0)

[[242]]
[1] "05/01/2018"
```

Been around the web a few times, have tried:

```
unlist(output$date)
```

With date being the column that is a list

tried using dplyr to do:

```
output2 <- data.frame(output) %>% mutate(output$Date %>% unlist())
```

tried use use.names=false

```
unlist(output$Date, use.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: Can you include a sample of your data with `dput`? We currently can't see what the issue is at all

Comment: `unlist(replace(v, lengths(v) == 0, NA_character_))`? It seems that you have a list column but shouldn't.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using `tidyr::unnest` to expand column containing `list` in a `data.frame`.

```
library(tidyr)

#Sample data.frame
df <- data.frame(sl = 1:2)
#List of dates added as 2nd column
df$Date <- list(A = c(as.Date("2018-01-01"), as.Date("2018-01-02"), as.Date("2018-01-03")),
                B = c(as.Date("2018-02-01"), as.Date("2018-02-02"), as.Date("2018-02-03")))

unnest(df)

#   sl       Date
# 1  1 2018-01-01
# 2  1 2018-01-02
# 3  1 2018-01-03
# 4  2 2018-02-01
# 5  2 2018-02-02
# 6  2 2018-02-03
```